# @model is Null for added classes not for original classes and it works if I use the prod server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

EDIT : I started over and was doing the MVCMovie tutorial.  Followed the steps. Still got the error using local db and local iis.
https://github.com/alecto-perfecto/WhatIsWrongWithMyComp/tree/main/WebApplication1

hmm could it be something with my local iis?

Strange thing I am experiencing. I cannot add regular controllers and views.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Throws an error. The model is null.

The 3 classes I made before these subsequent 3 all work normally. If I deploy to my website, it works. On my computer, however, it doesn't work.

Looking at the code, I can find no difference between the earlier files, and the later files. I have built, added a migration, and updated database. I can't figure this out.

I tried making a new model, and neither of the next two models I have are able to get the out of the box

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

View listed. Anyone face this before?
EDIT 9/23/2020

Example of one that works

```
public class Driver
{
    
    public int DriverID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cargo> Cargos { get; set; }

    public string DriverName { get; set; }

    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

example of one that doesnt work

```
       public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

  //  public ICollection<Cargo> Cargoes { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }

    public bool isPickUp { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
```

Youll notice I even took the ICollection out.  So just a basic model, Right clicked on Controller and added a new Controller.

On my prod server, I can create new with both driver and location.  On my local computer I can create new with driver but not location.  On location, the model is null and an error occurs for every editor for in the view.

Thanks for tip to edit

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all relevant content. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Thank you.  I am a bit scared as it is a NDA but I guess nothing is established.

Comment: If that's the case then do your best to make it into a very generic problem, and be sure to exclude any confidential information.

Comment: I see the link now. I was at work and couldnt check.  I will do that today

Comment: Im starting over to see if it still happens in a fresh project.

Comment: Thought I had it but I was wrong. =(

Comment: Edit/Details/List and I assume Delete all work. Why does the basic Create return View() not?

Comment: I can step through the the errors and the page loads. Could this be database based?  How do I upload asp.net code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer was it had something to do of my version of Visual Studio from reinstalling when I reset my PC.  When I got the preview version, everything worked fine.  So if you run into this issue, it may just be the version of Visual Studio and actually not you for once.

Answer (score 0):

I had gone from Visual Studio Enterprise to Visual Studio Community.  I assume this had something to do with it.  I changed database to Microsoft Azure. I was about to put the website on Azure, when I realized it didn't matter if I used my winhost or my local IIS. Finally, I felt assured it wasn't me and went to find a different version of VS community. Surprise, its not offered.  I had already reinstalled my OS, which means I had a clean VS Community.  I ended up opting for VS pro monthly.  Im contemplating the annual. Thats how I fixed it.